# Passing values of array into HTML text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

Let say I have a function that populates an array

```
function 1(){
  var array = []
  //do things 
  //array.push("stuffs")
```

How can I pass or iterate through this array into an HTML text box?

---

Edit for clarity

I am working with google apps script. 
I have a .gs file which runs server side.
I have an .html file which populates my UI.

In the .gs file I am populating an array based on information from a google sheet.

once I have this array I want to populate a text box in the .html file.

I am about 12 hours into html so I may not even understand this enough to articulate my questions correctly.

Comment: pass into single  or multiple textboxes?

Comment: what do you mean by pass?what you really want?

Answer (score 0):

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  t.data = SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
  return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

index.html:

```
<table>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

You can use same for input i guess.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: I don't think so. The array is populated server side. HTML is served up client side right?

Comment: then why dont you populate the array on client side?

Comment: I can see that I don't even really understand this enough to articulate what I want. I will edit the post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = '';
var array=['apple', 'peach','pear'];
$.each(array, function(index, item){
  html+='<input type="text" value="' + item + '"/>';  
});
$('body').append(html);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/1wa2pr8f/)**

Comment: So my array is in a server side function ( google apps script ) and I need to push that array to the HTML ( client side ). I know so little about jquery that I can't even figure out what is happening here.